# How can I get Virtualbox USB support work on Impish?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I've tried a lot of stuff to get USB support work on a Ubuntu Impish host system, however, with no success at all.

As recommended here on this site, I tried to to replace the distribution's version with Oracle Virtualbox OSE, however, Impish does not seem to be supported by Oracle yet. The package manager complains there is no release file available.
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/ doesn't list an `impish` folder.

```
webmaster@dev:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

I've installed the distribution packages:

```
root@dev:/home/webmaster# aptitude search virtualbox~i
i   virtualbox                      - Virtualisierungslösung für x86-Rechner - g
i A virtualbox-dkms                 - x86-Virtualisierungslösung - Quelldateien 
i   virtualbox-ext-pack             - zusätzliche Funktionen für VirtualBox, Dow
i   virtualbox-guest-additions-iso  - ISO-Abbild mit den Gasterweiterungen für V
i A virtualbox-qt                   - Virtualisierungslösung für x86-Rechner – G
```

Actually my unprivileged user starting the guest system is in the `vboxusers` group

```
root@dev:/home/webmaster# groups webmaster
webmaster : webmaster adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers
```

From my user having the `vboxusers` group there is no USB device shown.

```
webmaster@dev:~$ vboxmanage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

<none>
```

As superuser `vboxmanage` recognizes my USB devices, also the device in question Lovense USB dongle ID `1915:520a`, however, it is busy. No special software on the host is using this device but a bluetooth manager seems to auto-activate this bluetooth dongle even when I disable bluetooth and replug the dongle.

```
root@dev:/home/webmaster# vboxmanage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

UUID:               e5500226-2fd3-4aed-a59b-26e242c35269
VendorId:           0x1b3f (1B3F)
ProductId:          0x2019 (2019)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               3
USB version/speed:  1/Full
Manufacturer:       Yanmai
Product:            USB Microphone
SerialNumber:       QY306
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13.4//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/009
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               d24b6d59-febb-4572-b40a-11df5f576729
VendorId:           0x1915 (1915)
ProductId:          0x520a (520A)
Revision:           1.0 (0100)
Port:               4
USB version/speed:  2/Full
Manufacturer:       Lovense
Product:            USBDongle
SerialNumber:       000000000000
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/011
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               8ff86e8b-af61-47c8-9803-6a0605318745
VendorId:           0x1908 (1908)
ProductId:          0x0226 (0226)
Revision:           1.17 (0117)
Port:               2
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       GEMBIRD
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13.3//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/008
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               39de2cef-0f68-4672-9cd7-21f883e0bfe1
VendorId:           0x0e8d (0E8D)
ProductId:          0x201d (201D)
Revision:           255.255 (255255)
Port:               1
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       MediaTek
Product:            X5pro
SerialNumber:       0123456789ABCDEF
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/002
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               502cf2d5-ed75-4d01-92c6-62ea03ffbce8
VendorId:           0x0a12 (0A12)
ProductId:          0x0001 (0001)
Revision:           136.145 (136145)
Port:               13
USB version/speed:  2/Full
Manufacturer:       Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
Product:            CSR8510 A10
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-14//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/006
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               0551d730-3db3-4fbc-93a4-69dddb73dc8b
VendorId:           0x0480 (0480)
ProductId:          0xa202 (A202)
Revision:           3.21 (0321)
Port:               4
USB version/speed:  3/Super
Manufacturer:       TOSHIBA
Product:            External USB 3.0
SerialNumber:       20170630004479F
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-5//device:/dev/vboxusb/004/002
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               ffc259de-a8ad-4f1b-9dc7-e7564bfe87ce
VendorId:           0x046d (046D)
ProductId:          0xc52b (C52B)
Revision:           18.16 (1816)
Port:               1
USB version/speed:  2/Full
Manufacturer:       Logitech
Product:            USB Receiver
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13.2//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/007
Current State:      Busy

UUID:               fe29c73d-98c2-4f3d-a289-28e26cf10d5d
VendorId:           0x046d (046D)
ProductId:          0xc318 (C318)
Revision:           85.3 (8503)
Port:               3
USB version/speed:  2/Full
Manufacturer:       Logitech
Product:            Logitech Illuminated Keyboard
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4//device:/dev/vboxusb/003/003
Current State:      Busy
```

VM Settings:

```
webmaster@dev:~$ vboxmanage showvminfo Win10-64
Name:                        Win10-64
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Windows 10 (64-bit)
UUID:                        e26d34c1-5b18-4d71-8999-317effd0cff3
Config file:                 /wrk/old/vbox/Win10-64/Win10-64.vbox
Snapshot folder:             /wrk/old/vbox/Win10-64/Snapshots
Log folder:                  /wrk/old/vbox/Win10-64/Logs
Hardware UUID:               e26d34c1-5b18-4d71-8999-317effd0cff3
Memory size:                 4096MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   128MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    BIOS
Number of CPUs:              1
PAE:                         enabled
Long Mode:                   enabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      disabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               HardDisk
Boot Device 2:               Not Assigned
Boot Device 3:               Not Assigned
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      enabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
RTC:                         local time
Hardware Virtualization:     enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 disabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x Unrestricted Exec.:     enabled
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   HyperV
State:                       running (since 2021-12-12T02:07:46.768000000)
Graphics Controller:         VBoxSVGA
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             enabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:          
Teleporter Password:         
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:       
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:            
VM process priority:         default
Storage Controller Name (0):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (0):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      4
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
SATA (0, 0): /wrk/old/vbox/Win10-64/Win10-32.vdi (UUID: 670898b2-740c-414f-9231-71cf7495b406)
SATA (2, 0): /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso (UUID: 3503a64c-cb86-41ec-89d6-f68e19177266)
NIC 1:                       MAC: 0800272388A4, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:                       disabled
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: PulseAudio, Controller: HDA, Codec: STAC9221)
Audio playback:              enabled
Audio capture:               enabled
Clipboard Mode:              Bidirectional
Drag and drop Mode:          Bidirectional
Session name:                GUI/Qt
Video mode:                  1920x1440x32 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:                        disabled
OHCI USB:                    enabled
EHCI USB:                    enabled
xHCI USB:                    disabled

USB Device Filters:

Index:                       0
Active:                      yes
Name:                        Lovense Bluetooth Dongle
VendorId:                    1915
ProductId:                   520a
Revision:                    
Manufacturer:                
Product:                     
Remote:                      
Serial Number:               

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:

Name: 'vboxshare', Host path: '/wrk/vboxshare' (machine mapping), writable, auto-mount

VRDE Connection:             not active
Clients so far:              0

Capturing:                   active
Capture audio:               active
Capture screens:             0
Capture file:                /wrk/old/vbox/Win10-64/Win10-64.webm
Capture dimensions:          1024x768
Capture rate:                512kbps
Capture FPS:                 25kbps
Capture options:             vc_enabled=true,ac_enabled=true,ac_profile=med

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size: 0MB
OS type:                     Windows10_64
Additions run level:         3
Additions version:           5.2.22 r126460

Guest Facilities:

Facility "VirtualBox Base Driver": active/running (last update: 2021/12/12 02:07:53 UTC)
Facility "VirtualBox System Service": active/running (last update: 2021/12/12 02:08:14 UTC)
Facility "VirtualBox Desktop Integration": active/running (last update: 2021/12/12 02:11:56 UTC)
Facility "Seamless Mode": active/running (last update: 2021/12/12 02:11:56 UTC)
Facility "Graphics Mode": active/running (last update: 2021/12/12 02:11:56 UTC)
```

I even tried a catch-all-USB-filter in the VM, but no devices are found.

**Questions:**
How can I get USB support work on my host system?
How can I tell Ubuntu to let my Lovense bluetooth dongle untouched by the host system?
I've read somewhere, this could be a license problem and Oracle's OSE could fix the issue.
Can I install VirtualBox OSE for another compatible distribution on Ubuntu Impish? Which one?

Comment: You need to install the VirtualBox Extensions Pack and install it.  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads  Also, you need to make sure that your username is part of the `vboxusers` group `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER` in order for your USB to work in VirtualBox.  If you have not added your username to the `vboxusers` group, you will need to reboot the system after adding your username to the group.

Comment: @Terrance as mentioned in the question, both, the group is already assigned and the (distro's) extension pack is installed and recognized by VirtualBox as well.

Comment: Reinstalled the extension package from the VirtualBox website. At least I can select the USB microphone in the VM window's menu 'devices' now. Still struggeling with the Lovense dongle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for some reason the distibution's version of the VirtualBox extension package does not seem to support the USB functionality. As I have read somewhere else, there might be license issues.

The reinstall of the extension package from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds fixed the problem. (currently version 6.1.26)
The system will ask you to open the download with VirtualBox, which will start an upgrade process automatically.